# Aggregate multiple columns of qualitative data using pandas?

Tags: python, r, pandas, group-by, tidyr

I want to go from this:

|  | name | pet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rashida | dog |
| 2 | Rashida | cat |
| 3 | Jim | dog |
| 4 | JIm | dog |

to this:

|  | name | num_dogs | num_cats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | Rashida | 1 | 1 |

In R I would do

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(num_dogs = length(which(pet == "dog")),
            num_cats = length(which(pet == "cat")))
```

How would I do this using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to do this.

If you are filtering the value of a single column, then you can use the .agg with a custom lambda function.

```
(df.groupby(["name"])
  .agg(
      num_dogs=("pet", lambda x: np.sum(x == "dog")), 
      num_cats=("pet", lambda x: np.sum(x == "cat")))
)
```

Or

```
(df
  .groupby(["name", "pet"])
  .size()
  .unstack("pet", fill_value=0)
  .add_prefix("num_").add_suffix("s")
)
```

You can also use a pivot table.

```
df.reset_index().pivot_table(index="name", columns="pet", values="index", aggfunc="count", fill_value=0)
```

But if you need to filter based on two columns, then that approach will not work.  For example if you need to know how many old dogs.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ["Rashida", "Rashida", "Joe", "Joe"],
                   'pet': ['dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'],
                   'age': ["old", "old", "old", "young"]})
```

You can use the pivot table.

```
df.reset_index().pivot_table(index="name", columns=["pet", "age"], values="index", aggfunc="count", fill_value=0)
```

Or a crosstabs.

```
pd.crosstab(df["name"], [df["pet"], df["age"]], dropna=False).unstack().reset_index()
```

Or you can use the port of Dplyr called siuba to mimic the original R syntax but I haven't used this enough to know how to use it well.

```
from siuba import group_by, summarize, _
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), which is backended by pandas:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tribble, length, group_by, which, summarise
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.name,    f.pet,
...     "Rashida", "dog",
...     "Rashida", "cat",
...     "Jim",     "dog",
...     "Jim",     "dog",
... )
>>> 
>>> df >> group_by(f.name) >> summarise(
...     num_dogs = length(which(f.pet == "dog")),
...     num_cats = length(which(f.pet == "cat"))
... )
      name  num_dogs  num_cats
  <object>   <int64>   <int64>
0      Jim         2         0
1  Rashida         1         1
```